# Is there an efficient was to calculate a cyclical median in matlab?

Tags: matlab, median

I'm using matlab to mimic some c code that I've written so that I can replicate the result and plot it in matlab.

In c I am using an open source sliding median filter linked [here](http://ideone.com/8VVEa).

I am currently using medfilt1 to mimic it in matlab, but there are two problems.

1. It is SLOW! it would be ideal to have a similar filter in matlab, but I don't want to take the time to write one. If one does not exist, I'd like to at least be able to accomplish #2.
2. medfilt1 does not wrap around.

   `x = 1:5;
   medfilt1(x,3) % = 1 2 3 4 4`

It calculates the first values like

`median([0 1 2]) % = 1`

This is because medfilt1 uses zeros to fill in when you get near the edges. I would like a way to change this so that the first value is calculated like

`median([5 1 2]) % = 2`

```
medfiltcirc(x,3) % = 2 2 3 4 4
```

UPDATE: For fun, I wrote a sliding filter in matlab, and it turned out to be about 4x slower than using medfilt1 with padarray. Using `ordfilt2(padarray(x,[N/2 0],'circular'),N/2,ones(N,1))` proved to be even faster than medfilt1. I believe the only way to improve speed further would be to write a mex file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option is to use `padarray` before operating with the median filter:

```
x = medfilt1(padarray(1:5,[0 1],'circular'));
```

and take `x(2:end-1)` as the answer...

to improve `medfilt1` consider using `ordfilt2` for example:

```
x =  ordfilt2(1:5,2,[1 1 1]);
```

this should buy you up to a factor of two, read more about it [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html), and do pay attention to the variable class used for `A`...

Comment: If you intend to use the second parameter of `medifit1`, use `n=3;a=1:5;x = medfilt1(padarray(a,[0 (n-1)/2],'circular'),n);x=x((n-1)/2+1:end-(n-1)/2);`

Comment: yep, that will be the general solution, I trust the OP is intelligent enough to get that himself\herself...

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for something that wouldn't require calculating extra medians (I'm using a length 2048 filter), but this solves the problem

Comment: For maximal efficiency you can also consider working with `ordf.mex64` directly which ordfilt2 calls to...

Answer (score 1):

You can do the wrapping around yourself. Let the data be defined as

```
x = 1:5; %// data values
S = 3; %// block size
```

Then:

```
s = floor(S/2); %// how many elements need to be wrapped around
n = numel(x); %// length of x
result = medfilt1([x(n-s+1:n) x x(1:s)], S);
result = result(s+1:end-s);
```

Comment: This solution is wrapping around more than nessecary, wrapping 1 element on each side is sufficient in this case.

Comment: Hey, you're right! I added the `,3` later and didn't think of that. Good catch! Corrected now

Comment: Thanks @Luis, similar solution to accepted, however, using padarray is what will prevent an indexing nightmare.

Comment: @Trogdor Yes, `padarray` seems to be a simpler to use

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure that you're aware, circular statistics can be treacherous – [from the Wikipedia article on directional statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#Measures_of_location_and_spread):

> When data is concentrated, the median and mode may be defined by analogy to the linear case, but for more dispersed or multi-modal data, these concepts are not useful.

Have you looked at the [Circular statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10676-circular-statistics-toolbox--directional-statistics-) on the MathWorks File Exchange? It includes a [`circ_median`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10676-circular-statistics-toolbox--directional-statistics-/content/circ_median.m) function. I don't know how fast this function is in comparison to what you're using, but it might be a good starting point for optimization. A paper was published in the [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i10) on the toolbox ([alt link to PDF](http://kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/J-Stat-Softw-2009-Berens_6037%5b0%5d.pdf)). It might be a good idea to at least check if this function matches the output of other methods.